# Compiling static Python 3.6.5 binary for ARM

Tags: debian, compiling, python3

I'm trying, on Debian 9.4 x64, to compiling static Python 3.6.5 binary for Android (so arm32, arm64, ...).

I'm not sure of which library using to build Python 3.6.5 for arm and mips processors, for now i use "binutils-gold-2.29.1-16.1.armv7hl.rpm", but if another rpm is better for this usage please tel me wich one take.

- I tried to compile the binary with this following command:

  - `./configure --build=arm --prefix="$PWD"/out LDFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all -Wl,--export-dynamic" CPPFLAGS=-static CXXFLAGS=-static CFLAGS="-Os -static" LDFLAGS=-static LD=ld.gold`
- **EDIT**: And by typing this one: `make clean; make install`
- And i get this error:

  - `FIG_H -DUSE_PYEXPAT_CAPI -c ./Modules/expat/xmlparse.c -o Modules/xmlparse.o`
  - `./Modules/expat/xmlparse.c:92:3: error: #error You do not have support for any sources of high quality entropy enabled.`
  - `error  \`
  - `.Makefile:1874 : the recipe for the target « Modules/xmlparse.o » as failed`
  - `make: *** [Modules/xmlparse.o] Erreur 1`

I'm trying to find how i could fix this error, but unfortunatly the support webpage on Python website isn't very helpfull (https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildStatically).

**Finally, I would like to compile Python 3.6.5 for all processor platforms on which Android can run (arm32, aarm64, x86_x64, mips, mipsx64,...),  to finally get a one single binary file (i will repeat tasks for all other archs when i will have done with arm32).**

**So one file for each architectures cited, not multiple files/folders in output.
In a static way to avoid any dependencies with external libraries.
I chose to carry out the build operations, but if other less hazardous and simpler solutions exist i am taker.**

NB: all cmd line has been made through LXTerminal on root session by default.

Thanks by advance for help.

Comment: I'm guessing you might be missing some include files for the arm architecture. Googling for the filename gave me this [file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/expat/xmlparse.c)  we find that an error occurs if we don't have one of a bunch of C macro defines. [Searching the source code for one of these](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?utf8=✓&q=HAVE_GETRANDOM&type=) we find this is set [by configure](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3055c947f98a078bd10d6a8cc352048a1b771d60/configure.ac) (I think) after trying to execute a c code chunk.

Comment: Thanks for having reply, i just have check in "/python3.6.5/Modules/expat/" and i already have the "xmlparse.c" file, maybe i could take the one from the official git on the corresponding branch and replacing the file on my debian by the new one ? Although i only roughly understand what the error message (a problem with this file) means, i don't see what action i need to take.

Comment: Why are you using a binutils RPM on Debian?

Comment: @StephenKitt I use binutils RPM on my Debian because initially, i was following this tutorial (https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=57168101&postcount=2), which mentions this file, so I installed it, maybe i shouldn't have to?

Comment: **i already have the** I meant to say that you are missing *library header files* for the arm architecture (random.h) See this line of the configuration [https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3055c947f98a078bd10d6a8cc352048a1b771d60/configure.ac#L5404] you want to get this C sample to compile through your cross compiler (I think).

Comment: Ok, i just checked the corresponding line by your link, actually there is the part of the source-file: https://image.ibb.co/gGNR5o/1.jpg, and there is the part of my actual "random.h" file: https://image.ibb.co/gcxhd8/2.jpg, they looks like diferrent, maybe because i have launch the `./configure ...` command, maybe not i'm not pro in compilation. I will repeat me, but maybe that i should replace my "random.h" file with this one from Git? Or maybe i should setup another files/dependences ? I would like to get the static binary file for arm.

Comment: **I will repeat me, but maybe that i should replace my "random.h" file with this one from Git?** So I'm kind of guessing here but when you **cross-compile** (i.e. compile for a different architecture) you use a whole different set of libraries and header files which must be installed on your system. My guess is that you don't have these libraries. What I would be trying to do is extract out a compilation command that doesn't work and get it working. You might like to check out [this](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossCompiling) on cross compiling.